# How do I remove Azure role assignments with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I currently have a function app that is using RBAC and am trying to update the permissions. I am trying to run an Azure PowerShell command that will remove the role assignments, so I can then assign a new role.

I tried:

```
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(SecOpsConnection)
              ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
              azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
              Inline: |
                Remove-AzureAdMSRoleAssignment `
                  -Id {role guid}
```

Which results in:

```
Line |
   4 |  Remove-AzureAdMSRoleAssignment `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'Remove-AzureAdMSRoleAssignment' is not recognized as
     | a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
     | included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have also tried:

```
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(SecOpsConnection)
              ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
              azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
              Inline: |
                Remove-AzRoleAssignment `
                  -ObjectId {role guid} `
                  -RoleDefinitionName "Key Vault Certificates Officer" `
                  -ResourceGroupName "innovate-nprod-sandbox-eastus2-nextgen-rg"
```

Which results in:

```
Line |
   4 |  Remove-AzRoleAssignment `
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The provided information does not map to a role assignment.
```

I don't have permissions to remove a role assignment manually and have to do it through a pipeline  job. However, I'm not sure which cmdlet/parameters are needed to pass in. Am I missing information, using a wrong module?

Answer (score 0):

The `objectId` parameter of `remove-AzRoleAssignment` is meant to identify a user, security group or service principal, not the role as is shown in your example code.

> #### `-ObjectId`
>
> Azure AD ObjectId of the user, group or service principal.

Next to this:

> Use the `Remove-AzRoleAssignment` commandlet to revoke access to any principal at given scope and given role. The object of the assignment i.e. the principal MUST be specified. The principal can be a user (**use SignInName or ObjectId parameters to identify a user**), security group (use ObjectId parameter to identify a group) or service principal (use ServicePrincipalName or ObjectId parameters to identify a ServicePrincipal. **The role that the principal is assigned to MUST be specified using the RoleDefinitionName parameter**.

More information: [Remove-AzRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azroleassignment)